# MySql - How to have expressions with in select with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have the following columns `Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6`.

I want to do a Group By on `col1` and `col2` and then want to calculate an expression for the following columns `sum(col4)+sum(col5)+sum(col6)/sum(col3)`.

Is it possible to do it in single step or do i need to write a procedure for this.
If procedure is required, can some one guide me, how can i write a generic procedure ,in which i can specify tablename, string containing column names, and expression as argument

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do it simply like

```
SELECT (
           (sum(col4)+sum(col5)+sum(col6))
           /sum(col3)
       ) AS TOTAL 
FROM MY_TABLE 
GROUP BY col1,col2
```

And after it you can access `TOTAL` as a field in your script/program

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it in single query. 
SELECT   SUM (col3) + SUM (col4) + SUM (col5) / SUM (col6)
    FROM test_table
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

single query

```
SELECT   (SUM (col4) + SUM (col5) + SUM (col6)) / SUM (col3) as cal
    FROM calc
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, sum(col4)+sum(col5)+sum(col6)/sum(col3) as SUM
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single step as

```
SELECT (SUM(col4)+SUM(col5)+SUM(col6)/SUM(col3)) AS RESULT  FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY col1,col2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by two queries according to the format you want to display the result

first one is

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, sum(col4)+sum(col5)+sum(col6)/sum(col3) as SUM
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Col1, Col2;
```

second is

```
SELECT   SUM (col3) + SUM (col4) + SUM (col5) / SUM (col6) as SUM
FROM your_table
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```